# Conflicting informations about Kinect

Tags: kinect, sensors, depth, motion, openni

I wanted to start making an application using motion controls (using depth sensors) but I don't know where to start. I was looking for a *current* comparison of available hardware and software options. Such as Asus Xiton, the Kinect SDK, and OpenNI
But unfortunately I was unsuccessful. Either the info was old or conflicting. I'd like to know what can be done with given hardware/software setup(also which is 'easier' to start) and then choose one. 
I'd appreciate any info/links.

Comment: What operating system do you have and what sort of app are you thinking? Do you need RGB data? Does it need to be portable?

Answer (score 0):

if you want something easy, Kinect with Kinect SDK is definitely the easiest option out there in the market.

however do note that kinect is a consumer grade product hence it accuracy and resolution will not be comparable to other device from primesense.